# Div Bootstrap and form

Tags: css

How to do with bootstrap a div that occupies the entire screen and to its right on the image put a form

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSWAV.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps you. This is an example.[example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-baafjx?file=index.html)